# How to prove $\|Tx\|<\|T\|$ where T is bounded linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory

I have bounded linear operator $T$ and an element $x$ belong to domain of $T$. Now I am going to prove that there is strict inequality $\left \|Tx \right \|< \left \|T \right \|$
As we know that for any operator $T$ we can write $\left \|Tx \right \| \leq \left \|T \right\|\cdot \left \|x \right \| \leq \left \|T \right \|$. My question how to prove strict inequality

Comment: You cannot prove it. It is false.

Comment: You can't in general.

Comment: Are there some restrictions on $x$? Such as, perhaps, $\|x\|<1$? What space are we working on? (Can it be infinite-dimensional?)

Comment: If we take ||x||<1 then is it true

Answer (score 3):

If $T$ is an isometric isomorphism then $\|Tx\|=\|x\|=\|T\|\|x\|$ for all $x$

If $\|x\|<1$ and $T$ is any non-zero operator then $\|Tx\|\leq \|T\|\|x\|<\|T\|$ so strict inequality is true.

Comment: If we take ||x||<1 and X is space of any dimension, then does ||Tx||<||T|| hold?

Comment: @UmerJadoon See my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

This is false. For example, consider $T=1_X$ where $X$ is a normed space. Then $\Vert T \Vert = 1$ yet $\Vert Tx \Vert = \Vert x \Vert$ can be made arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the question asked : whether there is no restriction imposed on the $\Vert x \Vert$ - the statement is false, because you may rescale $x$ by an arbitrary factor. Whether it is assumed, that $\Vert x \Vert  = 1$, then, by definition of operator norm:
$$
\Vert T \Vert = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert  = 1} \Vert T x \Vert
$$
we have non-strict inequality in general. In case the value on which $\sup$ is reach, doesn't belong to the domain, the inequality becomes strict.

Comment: If ||x||<1 then what happens

Comment: @UmerJadoon then the inequality is always strict